# Why can't I assign a JSON response to a variable for using later?

Tags: swift, xcode

I assigned a variable to a json response that is an array. The problem is I cannot access it later because it says it has no subscripts. I have to access the original variable(constant, actually) to get the info I need from the response. Hopefully the code will be clearer.

```
let data = (try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path!), options: .mappedIfSafe))
        do {
            // data we are getting from network request
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let response = try decoder.decode(Recipes.self, from: data!)

            let recipes = response.recipe

for (index, recipes) in recipes.enumerated(){
        //This prints the info ok!
                print(response.recipe[index].name)
                print(response.recipe[index].nutrients.protein)
                print(response.recipe[index].steps[2])

//This does't and it says it has no subscripts!
                print(recipes[index].name)
                print(recipes[index].nutrients.protein)
                print(recipes[index].steps[2])
}
  } catch { print(error) }
```

Error: Value of type 'Recipe' has no subscripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all please name an item in a `for` loop always in singular form to avoid confusion and the error (the name of the loop element variable hides the *same* name of the array variable).

```
for (index, recipe) in recipes.enumerated() { ...
```

then the line

```
print(recipes[index].name)
```

will work. However you can write simpler

```
print(recipe.name)
```